# Plotting Data with Basemap

Tags: mask, matplotlib-basemap, contourf

I am trying to plot the following dataset using a Basemap instance:

`[-0.126929 -0.127279 -0.127851 ..., -0.14199  -0.142828 -0.14335 ]`

The problem is I can't have the right number of points displayed on the map. (which is the length of my data list above = 1315 points).

If I define my dataset to be like:

> data = np.diag(data)

`[[-0.126929  0.        0.       ...,  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.       -0.127279  0.       ...,  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.       -0.127851 ...,  0.        0.        0.      ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ..., -0.14199   0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...,  0.       -0.142828  0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...,  0.        0.       -0.14335 ]]`

I have this figure
[image]

If I define my dataset to be like:

> data = np.ma.masked_where(data==0., data)

`[[-0.12692899999999696 -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -0.12727900000000147 -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -0.12785099999999971 ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -0.14198999999999984 -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -0.1428280000000015 --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- -0.1433499999999981]]`

I have this figure
[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()     

m = Basemap(projection='mill',      \
            llcrnrlon= lonmin-0.02, \
            urcrnrlon= lonmax+0.02, \
            llcrnrlat= latmin-0.02, \
            urcrnrlat= latmax+0.02, \
            resolution='f')     

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('bwr_r')

x, y = m(*np.meshgrid(lon,lat))
y = y.T 
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,cmap=cmap)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.,color='grey')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1.5,color='white')
m.drawmapboundary(color='k',linewidth=2.0)
m.fillcontinents(color='white')           

cb = m.colorbar(cs,location='bottom',size='5%',pad='8%')
cb.set_label('[m]',fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```